# Android : Design shown in XML not reflected in the UI

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am working on an Android application in which I am displaying notes on the app. The problem I was facing before when I was specifying size of 180X180DP for noteImage was that the right-side of the image was getting chopped. So I specified match_parent.

When I do that, the XML preview shows it properly, but when I run the app, the text goes below and outside the image, the image also moves down, and the headline(subject) moves up. Check the screenshot below :

[image: How image is messed up]

What I would like to do is something like below, only with 2 columns I am doing by using GridView and specifying columns = 2; but square shaped images. I have already specified the List as GridView in code.
[image]

XML file which shows the layout.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2.5dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noteImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteTag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:id="@+id/noteText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Kindly let me know what I can do. Thanks a lot. :-)

*Updated XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2.5dip" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
     <!--   <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/noteImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            />-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/noteTag"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="178dp"
            android:id="@+id/noteText"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Updated Screenshot : http://postimg.org/image/mgmzca8nx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `android:background="@drawable/your_drawable"` or `android:background="@color/your_color"` on the TextView.

Something like this:

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@color/magenta"
   android:padding="16dp"/>
```

Comment: Nope, that didn't help, it completely messed up the whole thing, and the images were overlapping. I don't want to use color or background, can you explain me how is that relevant in placing the elements properly.

Comment: Don't use ImageViews, set the drawable or the color what you want to the TextView with android:background="" attribute.

Comment: I set the background via code for both, now the image is also chopped as well as text is getting cut. Can you see the updated XML file as well as screenshot on http://postimg.org/image/mgmzca8nx/

Comment: Ok, by setting the height it worked. Thanks a lot. :-)